# How to skip LoginActivity after a successful try the first time you run the Android app

Tags: java, android, android-layout, authentication, skip

I'm new to Java/Android programming. I'm getting to know how the layout works and how to redirect it. I've got a splash screen > login > main . Now I want to skip the login activity. How can I do it ?

---

**Edit:**

This is what my code looks like now, after answer:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPref", 0); 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("Bool", true);
editor.commit();
```

How I check from my Splashscreen:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPref", 0); 
   if (prefs.getBoolean("Bool", false)) { //login_activity; }
   else{ //maint_activity;
```

I think this would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SharedPreferences` to store some `boolean` value like `skipLogin`. During splash screen you can check this value, and display login or main, depending on result.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I edit my post on how i implemented my SharePrefrences

Comment: @JeffEdward Yeah. Remember that values stored in `SharedPreferences` are not cleaned when you force close application or application crashes. You need to clean it manually in your application, if you decide to let user login again (or clean application data in Application Manager).

Comment: Thanks! , Im still learning. So, if i press the logout i should rewrite the bool value back to false. Yes?

Answer (score 0):

Simple logic, during the splash screen run the following method:

```
if(login){
   redirects to main
}
else{
   redirects to login
}
```